# Confused about router view default content

Tags: vuejs3

I am confused about how to use default content of router-view,codes first,see below my router.js, App.vue and User.vue
router.js

```
export const router = createRouter(
{
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes:[
        {
            path:'/',
            name:'home',
            component:() => import('../App.vue'),
            meta:{ isAccessed: true }
        },
        {
            path:'/:userName',
            name:'user',
            component:() => import('../components/User.vue'),
            meta:{ isAccessed: true }
        },
    ]
}
)
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>
    <router-view>
      <input v-if="route.name === 'home'" 
       v-model="userName" @keyup.enter="jumpUserPage(userName)" 
       type="text"/>
    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

User.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="route.name === 'user'">
    <div>{{route.params.userName}}</div>
    <button @click="queryUserScore(route.params.userName)">
Query Score</button>
  </div>
  <router-view v-if="route.name !== 'user'"/>   
</template>
```

I have put an input tag into router-view of App.vue, when user type some texts and hit enter to jump to User.vue, like from http://localhost:8080/ to http://localhost:8080/emma, the problem is when jump User, content of User.vue will not be displayed. Could someone show me what error is and how to fix.

Comment: As per my knowledge making App.vue as a router-based component itself is not a good idea. App.vue  would act as an entry point for the Vue application (without router module) when you wanna make SPA with the power of routing then <router-view> should be part of the App.vue template in general.  I would suggest implementing Home.Vue and User.vue then mapping them with /home or '/' and /user routes and using <router-view></router-view>  as part of App.vue.
Please look at below link for further information
 https://saidhayani.medium.com/understand-routing-in-vue-js-with-examples-6da96979c8e3

Comment: thanks for ur reply, I have got what you said. but my problem is when jumping user component, content of user will not be displayed.